# How to use an array inside any mongoose model in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

```
    const writingSchema = {
      title: String,
      content: String
    };
    
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
      email: String,
      password: String,
      userID: String,
      userName: String,
      yourWriting: new Array(writingSchema)
    });
```

*Is this the correct format to declare an array inside the object in Node JS*

Answer (score 2):

We can declare an array of [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) in Mongoose like:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  userID: String,
  userName: String,
  yourWriting: [writingSchema]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const writingSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    userID: String,
    userName: String,
    yourWriting: [writingSchema]
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html